# some uniform convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and

let $\displaystyle f_n(x)=\dfrac{x-a} {n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+\dfrac{k(x-a)}{n}\right)$

so, $f_n$ is uniformly convergence when $[a,b]$?

I think $f_n(x)$ is pointwise convergence, but I don't know that is uniform convergence or not..

Comment: The pointwise limit of $\{f_n\}$ is clearly $F(x)=\int_a^xf(x)dx$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$. We need monotonicity to use Dini though.

Comment: With $\displaystyle x_k = a + \frac{k(x-a)}{n}$ we have $\left|f_n(x) - \int_a^x f(t) \, dt \right| \leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} |f(x_k)-f(t)| \, dt$.  Use the uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$. No monotonicity is needed here.